# Passing a c# Textbox as a javascript parameter in IE (Chrome works)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

When "btnBold" is pressed a method is called passing a textbox as a parameter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {    
   function ChangeText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
      ...
      ...
      ...
   }
   $('#btnBold').click(function()
   {
       ChangeText(<%=TextTitu.ClientID%>, "<b>", "</b>");
   });

});
```

```
<button id='btnBold' value='Bold' style="width:20px;"><b>b</b></button>    
<asp:textbox id="TextTitu" tabIndex="1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:textbox>
```

Works just fine in google chrome, for some reason i can't make it work in IE

**Error: 'ctl00_c_area_conteudo_TextTitu' is not defined**

When i open the HTML code i can easily find ctl00_c_area_conteudo_TextTitu there

Comment: Unless you have a variable called `ctl00_c_area_conteudo_TextTitu`, it shouldn't work in any browser. Do you mean to pass a string as the first parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap `<%=TextTitu.ClientID%>` in quotes, like so:

```
ChangeText("<%=TextTitu.ClientID%>", "<b>", "</b>");
```

Your current code evaluates into:

```
ChangeText(ctl00_c_area_conteudo_TextTitu, "<b>", "</b>");
```

But `ctl00_c_area_conteudo_TextTitu` is not defined as a variable anywhere, which is why the error is thrown. After wrapping it in quotes the code will evaluate to:

```
ChangeText("ctl00_c_area_conteudo_TextTitu", "<b>", "</b>");
```

According to your ChangeText function, you could then use either `document.getElementById(elementID)` (with pure JavaScript) or if you're using a library like jQuery you could obtain the control with the selector `$("#" + elementID)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `getElementById('<%=TextTitu.ClientID%>')` in order to get a reference to the textbox.

Or, since it looks like you're using jQuery, you can pass in the ID as a string and use:

`$('#' + elementID);`

Your new code would be something like this (see comments):

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
   function ChangeText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
      //Get the element to use later
      var $elem = $('#' + elementID);
      ...
      ...
      ...
   }

   $('#btnBold').click(function()
   {
       //Note we're wrapping it in quotes here
       ChangeText("<%=TextTitu.ClientID%>", "<b>", "</b>");
   });

});
```

Comment: THANK YOU, it works just fine...god bless you for your patience and time spend